# How to get updated html element in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have displayed inbuild html content in angular(7) UI with help of **DomSanitizer**

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("htmlstr")
```

After sanitized content in html view:

```
<div><input type=text value=inp/></div>
```

User can modify the value like whatever they want.

I have tried to get whole html content with updated value, but I could not get latest content. It always return DOM source.

```
current output - <div><input type=text value=inp/></div>
Expected output - <div><input type=text value=upd/></div>
```

Kindly anyone help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are you trying to update whole html. If there is no specific reason to do so you may try.

The reason you always get same value is because static values are not updated in angular. You have to assign a classVariable to hold values.
I would be nice to use interpolation in angular if you just want to change value.

in your html

In your ts create a class variable
valueVariable = "";

use [(ngmodel)] if you want two way  binding.
or reactive forms.

Now if you get your value back it will be updated

Comment: Because we get html response, also need to pass the same into service provider.

Comment: while using {{val}}, it printed as a string I want to display this content as html